# Dragging shapes

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi I'm beginner and I'm doing a java program with swing that selects a shape and then drags it to make and draw a shape on screen (see picture below).

[image]

But I have some problems:

1. When I draw a new shape, the first one disappear.
2. The shape can be drawn out of borders (see picture below)
3. I just can drag from left to right, I can not drag from right to left.

Screenshot for 2):

[image]

This is my DrawPanel class:

```
class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

    public DrawingPanel() {

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        if (x == 1) {

            drawCircle(g);
        }

        else if (x == 2) {

            drawOval(g);
        }

        else if (x == 3) {

            drawRectangle(g);
        }

        else if (x == 4) {

            drawSquare(g);
        }

        else if (x == 5) {

            drawLine(g);
        }



    }

    public void drawCircle(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(xStrart, yStrart, width, width);

    }

    public void drawOval(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(xStrart, yStrart, width, height);

    }

    public void drawRectangle(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(xStrart, yStrart, width, height);

    }

    public void drawSquare(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(xStrart, yStrart, width, width);

    }

    public void drawLine(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawLine(xStrart, yStrart, xEnd, yEnd);

    }

}
```

Comment: You dont' want to override paint method, instead override paintComponent. Also, you would better keep a list of shapes, if you don't your new xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd will obviously replace the old ones. When panel repaints, shapes will be cleared, you have to store them all and paint every single one.

Comment: how can I do array of shapes of type DrawingPanel ?

Comment: Your shapes will not be of type DrawingPanel. You can use the [Shape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) interface, which is implemented by classes representing rectangles, ellipses and lines, or create your own shape class if you need something more. If you use a `ArrayList <Shape>`, then you can easily paint all your shapes by invonking `g.draw (Shape s)`, where `g` is your `Graphics2D` object, which you can obtain by casting your `Graphics` (in `paintComponent (Graphics g)` method)

Comment: See [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a working example of drawing a shape from an ArrayList in the paintComponent() method.